# Orchard: Attaching a content part on-demand

Tags: orchardcms

I am working on a Forms Module which provides a FormPart. In the edit mode of this Part i've a listing of other ContentParts (those which implement a custom interface IForm). User can then choose one content part from the available list. The edit mode view of choosen Content Part should then be available underneath. If user changes his selection of content part the edit view should also reflect this change and load appropriate content part.

I know i can Weld Content Parts to content types using ContentHandlers but here the request has already been served and in Edit Mode view the user will specify what content part he wants to be welded.

Any suggestions or insights would be highly thankful.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the IContentDefinitionService in Orchard.ContentTypes there are several methods that you will probably find useful, primarily this one:

```
void AddPartToType(string partName, string typeName);
```

Use the source ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The method that you specified and others for Welding parts would be useful while the request is being processed on Server Side. Here the case is different. The request has already been served. On client side user will get a listing of ContentParts that he would like to be welded. I believe some Ajax based solution would work which would request the Edit Mode View of the selected Part on the go and append it underneath.

Comment: One solution that i can think of is first get the required selection from user and inform that a page refresh is required. On page re-fresh i will then have a chance of attaching my required Part. But an Ajax based solution would be very nice which won't require the user to refresh the page first.